# How to retrieve the Selected checkbox names ( Multiple Selected) in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I had multiple checkbox which is generated using loop. After submitting the form I want to get the names of the selected individual checkbox to store it in database as id. Please help me.. Thanks in advance

Code i used for generating checkbox in loop:

```
while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsrcResult)) 
  {
      $strA = $arrayRow["area_id"];
  $strB = $arrayRow["area_name"];
      echo "<div class=\"area_check\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"covarea[] \" />$strB</input></div>";
  }
```

This code I used for getting names for it didnt worked. It only returned state of check box as ON

```
 while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($box)) 
{
  $aid=$val;
  echo $aid;
}
```

Comment: @Raj Please edit your question and post the generated HTML code, and also elaborate on what "store it in database as id" means exactly.

Comment: This code sample is of little value without knowing (for example) what $strB is.

Answer (score 2):

If the set of checkboxes is marked up as so

```
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="Cheese">
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="Ham">
```

Then any checked values are accessed as an array from $_POST['food']

Obviously with a code example, as @rajasekar points out, it would be easier to recommend an approach

Comment: I meant to say as @sico87 pointed out, of course!

You might also want to look at previous questions - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=checkboxes+php

Answer (score 0):

- The **id** for each element is optional, but should/must be unique.
- Form elements must have a **name** attribute, or they will not be submitted (use "covarea[]" for the name for all the chexboxes.
- Checkboxes must have a **value** attribute, or they will be submitted with value "*on*".
- You must ensure that **$strA** and **$strB** do not have HTML meta characters or your generated HTML will be invalid.
- Your example had a space after the "[]" in the **id**, btw.

Perhaps like this.

```
$n = 0;
while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsrcResult)) 
{
     $strA = $arrayRow["area_id"];
     $strB = $arrayRow["area_name"];
     $n++;
     echo "<div class=\"area_check\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"covarea${n}\" name=\"covarea[]\" value=\"${strA}\"/>$strB</input></div>";
}
```